# Quebec Provincial Crown Lands

Tags: data-request, government, geospatial, canada

I'm attempting to gather and identify limits of Crown Land in the province of Quebec, Canada.

I'm coming at this from a GIS background and am trying to create a database that resembles the information available on this portal: [Crown Land Use Policy Atlas Ontario](http://www.giscoeapp.lrc.gov.on.ca/CLUPA/Index.html?site=CLUPA&viewer=CLUPA&locale=en-US). Crown land is generally federal land that isn't zoned as urban/developed, agricultural, privately owned, or an environmental protected area.

Since a portal like this doesn't exist for Quebec, I figured that this could be teased out using the following open licensed information and data:

- [Census Boundaries for Land, Water, and other limits (StatsCan)](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm)
- [Administrative Regions of Quebec (MERN)](http://mern.gouv.qc.ca/territoire/portrait/portrait-donnees-mille.jsp)
- [Unorganized Regions of Quebec (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unorganized_territories_in_Quebec)
- [Protected Areas Boundaries for Quebec (NRCan)](http://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/6c51dc92-1f37-5895-9c81-837d8e8f484e)

I would like to know if there exists either an open licensed shape of crown lands available for Quebec or, alternatively, an open licensed boundary of Resource Extraction Areas (French: `Zone d'exploitation contrôlée`, or `ZECs`, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_d%27exploitation_contr%C3%B4l%C3%A9e)), as that is the final piece of information I need to ascertain what is technical "Crown Land" from the information I've gathered.

Any advice on the Crown Land identification approach is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this dataset but I think it might be useful: [Unités d'aménagement (UA)](https://www.donneesquebec.ca/recherche/fr/dataset/unite-d-amenagement)

> L'unité d'aménagement (UA) est une unité territoriale de référence qui s'applique sur les territoires forestiers du domaine de l'État en vertu de l'article 13 de la Loi sur l'aménagement durable du territoire forestier (LADTF). On dénombre actuellement 71 UA sur le territoire forestier public québécois. La stratégie d'aménagement durable des forêts prévoit des orientations et des objectifs d’aménagement durable des forêts pour ce territoire forestier. Cette délimitation du territoire forestier a pour but de circonscrire des aires pour la production des ressources. Ainsi, le ministre peut accorder divers droits forestiers sur ce territoire.

Google translate makes this:

> The management unit (UA) is a territorial unit of reference that applies to forest lands in the domain of the state under section 13 of the Sustainable Forest Management Act (FSAA) . At present, there are 71 AUs in Québec's public forest area. The Sustainable Forest Management Strategy provides guidance and objectives for sustainable forest management for this forest area. The purpose of this delimitation of forest land is to define areas for the production of resources. Thus, the Minister may grant various forest rights in this territory.

Comment: I have heavily edited your answer, because it was only a link. We like some background in answers on SE sites ;-)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this data set but some of the boundaries do coincide with the ZECs I'm interested in. I need to read up more on Article 13 of LADTF as I wasn't aware of it previously. This isn't exactly what I need but this is certainly useful for the research purposes I have in mind. Thanks!